# Not able to retrieve value which is passed between pages

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, function

This is how i call an iframe and pass data

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         function refreshConversatio() {
             document.getElementById('iframeDisplayMessage').src = 'Message.aspx?id=' + document.getElementById('val').value;
             }
</script>
```

And this is how i receive value, But how do i recieve value through Hiddenfield??

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function getParameterByName(name) {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
            var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
                results = regex.exec(location.search);
            return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
        function myLoad() {
            document.getElementById('divConversation').innerText = getParameterByName("id");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#a32c05;" >
       <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hidden1" name="hidden1" />
    <div id="divConversation"></div>

    <script>
        myLoad();
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var hiddenId = document.getElementById('<%hidden1.ClientId%>');
hiddenId.value=getParameterByName("id");
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('<%hidden1.ClientId%>').value=getParameterByName("id");`


I want something meaningful like this

Comment: Sir, does your code work for u? It's not workinf for me at the moment

Comment: What is not working? If your getParameterByName function works, it should work.

Comment: Do You mean that on server side ` Response.Write(hidden1.Value);`  will give the value contained in getParameterByName("id");

Comment: Because using you code i'm not able to use hidden value on cs page

Comment: Please edit and rephrase your original question as I'm obviously missing the point.

Comment: If you need to know the id on the server side on page load, use Response["id"]